# How to put a " in asp:ListItem of asp:ListBox

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I'm trying to display a " in the Text of asp:ListItem of a ListBox I've defined, I've tried to do it by inserting a \ before the " but it's no use. I can't think in anything else that could make it work properly.

Do you have any idea of what could I do? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly you want to add a " charater in the Text of the asp:ListItem. 

Try this: 
`<asp:ListItem Text='"'>`

Another option could be:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="test1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="test2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="test3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="test4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>
        "
    </asp:ListItem>

</asp:ListBox>
```